# Not able to add cv2.GaussianBlur() to Keras Sequential model

Tags: python-3.x, keras, opencv, python

The code is

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Lambda(lambda x:cv2.GaussianBlur(x, (3,3), 0), input_shape=(160, 320, 3)))
```

And I have got this error:

```
TypeError: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

#### How can I create a pipeline of image processing functions to my input image. Should I create a user defined function and then add it to my layer. If so , kindly show an example